# Problem with inventory replication on Unreal Engine 4

Tags: replication, unreal-engine4, multiplayer, inventory

I made an inventory system on UE4, but to do the inventory itself I created a component which represent the inventory of the player and the inventory of lootable vehicles.

The problem is that when I take a stuff in the vehicle's inventory, I delete it from the inventory and create a slot in the player inventory to store the item. But the slot refresh is made in the HUD so I don't know how to replicate it. Should I recode this whole part in the BP_character rather than the in HUD?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not some professional and I'm having issues of my own with the same area you're working on, but what I think you do want your inventory as a component on your character (with an array and inventory logic stuff in the component blueprint). Then, whenever the player opens their appropriate HUD to view their inventory, it loads the HUD according to what's in the inventory component's array. All changes to the array should be done explicitly by the server (by making sure it's replicated and doing authority checks anywhere you make updates to the array.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track as the HUD is not the place to keep your inventory. The character is a better place but the best place to keep it is in the GameInstance.

The GameInstance is a persistent class that is always available from anywhere in the game. This makes it very useful for many things besides your inventory.

Keeping the inventory here means you can use code anywhere you like to move items to or from the player's inventory. E.g. if an NPC wants to give an item to the player, you can do that with code on the NPC class, because the NPC class can see the player's inventory.

Likewise, if the inventory is on the GameInstance, the HUD can also see it.